# Can you rotate a sprite node x + or - amount of degrees instead of an exact value

Tags: sprite-kit

For example

```
let rotateAction = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 4), duration: 0)
```

I know this sets a sprite's z rotation to 45 degrees, but what if I wanted to add +45 or -45 degrees relative to where the sprite currently is. For example if the sprite's initial z rotation is at 15 degrees and I want it to be at 60 then 105 ( or -30 then -75 if it's negative), is that possible?

Comment: see rotate byAngle [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417805-rotate)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
SKAction.rotate(byAngle: ..., duration: ...)
SKSpriteNode().zRotation += / -= ...
```